# grep with regex wrongly selects unicode characters

Tags: regex, unix, unicode, grep

I have run grep with the following regex:

`grep -e "^[a-zA-Z]" file.txt`

the point is to only get lines that start with alphabetic characters in the ascii range, which works, if I explicitly type out the alphabet like

`grep -e "^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]" file.txt`

which is odd already, because that's what `[a-zA-Z]` is supposed to specify. When I look at my input data's matches with the first regex, we get matches like:

`ﬁ`
`ﬂ`

notice that fi and fl are one character in these cases.

Technically, the explicit typing of the alphabet is a solution, but I'd rather want to

- know why `[a-zA-Z]` doesn't work
- if a sensible solution exists, see what that'd look like.

Comment: Purely as an aside - avoid the [UUoC](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2002#:~:text=cat%20is%20a%20tool%20for,input%2C%20like%20tail%20or%20tar%20.). Make it a *habit* to watch for this and fix it while you are typing the command. While it might not be worthwhile to go back and refactor working production code, the effort of changing/establishing the habit will improve the quality of all your code over time. Upvote on the question in general, though. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

grep is locale aware. `[a-zA-Z]` can match non-ASCII characters depending on your locale (e.g. á, ä, ø, æ). To force ASCII (and not handle any multibyte characters), set the C locale:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -e '^[a-zA-Z]' file.txt
```