# Bash regex vs. diacritics

Tags: regex, bash, diacritics

I do some regex checking in Bash to make sure that a string contains only sane characters (only lowercase a-z in this case) and I encountered this strange behavior.

It looks the same in `grep` and `sed`.
Python 3.9 behaves as I would expect it.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?
If it is a bug, where to report it?

---

Lowercase `š` is wrongly detected as a character between `a-z`:

```bash
[[ 'š' =~ ^[a-z]$ ]] && echo sane || echo nope
sane

[[ 'š' =~ [a-z] ]] && echo sane || echo nope
sane

grep '^[a-z]$' <<<'š' && echo sane || echo nope
š
sane

sed 's/^[a-z]$/a/' <<<'š'
a
```

Lowercase `ž` is correctly detected as not a character between `a-z`:
**EDIT:** Because `ž` goes right after `z` - that is outside of `a-z`.

```bash
[[ 'ž' =~ ^[a-z]$ ]] && echo sane || echo nope
nope

[[ 'ž' =~ [a-z] ]] && echo sane || echo nope
nope

grep '^[a-z]$' <<<'ž' && echo sane || echo nope
nope

sed 's/^[a-z]$/a/' <<<'ž'
ž
```

Capital `Š` is correctly detected as not a character between `a-z`:

```bash
[[ 'Š' =~ ^[a-z]$ ]] && echo sane || echo nope
nope

[[ 'Š' =~ [a-z] ]] && echo sane || echo nope
nope

grep '^[a-z]$' <<<'Š' && echo sane || echo nope
nope

sed 's/^[a-z]$/a/' <<<'Š'
Š
```

Capital `Š` is wrongly detected as a character between `A-Z`:

```bash
[[ 'Š' =~ ^[A-Z]$ ]] && echo sane || echo nope
sane

[[ 'Š' =~ [A-Z] ]] && echo sane || echo nope
sane

grep '^[A-Z]$' <<<'Š' && echo sane || echo nope
Š
sane

sed 's/^[A-Z]$/A/' <<<'Š'
A
```

My `bash` version:

```
GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

My `grep` version:

```
grep (GNU grep) 3.6
```

My `sed` version:

```
sed (GNU sed) 4.8
```

My locale:

```
locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Python:

```
python3 -c 'import re ;print("sane" if re.match(r"^[a-z]$", "š") else "nope")'
nope

python3 -c 'import re ;print("sane" if re.match(r"^[a-z]$", "s") else "nope")'
sane
```

---

**EDIT:**

As [@oguz-ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678/oguz-ismail) pointed out, `ž` was just a badly chosen outlier (literally) as it goes after `z`.
The behavior looks consistent with characters between `a-z` in alphabetical order - like `š` and `č`.
And to get rid of them all, I had to set `LC_ALL=C`.

```
[[ 'č' =~ ^[a-z]$ ]] && echo sane || echo nope
sane

LC_CTYPE=C
# or stronger: LC_ALL=C

[[ 'č' =~ ^[a-z]$ ]] && echo sane || echo nope
nope
```

My last questio is whether it is expected to match letters with diacritics with the `[a-z]` range.
(Definitely not expected by me.)

Comment: As three marks: 100% correct on MacOS but not on [Tio](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzpaQf3oQnUF2zqFuOhE3apYFYXYWAU1NYXU5Ix8heLEvFSFmhoIJy@/IJWLC0kDWD0xyveRav4@0sxfADXfUTeKOPMhGsDq8Sv//x8A) or [IDE One](https://ideone.com/M7dUIH)

Comment: It looks ok to me, derivations of s may fall between a-z, and it makes sense that that of z don't. Have you tried `LC_ALL=C`?

Comment: On OSX `[[ 'š' =~ ^[a-z]$ ]]` is not matching

Comment: Is `'š'` in the range of `[a-z]`? If the OP is specifically looking for ascii, it is not...

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks. This is the answer I was looking for. If you post it as an answer, I will mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: If you want a range and reject all non-ascii characters, use `[[ $urchar =~ ^[\x61-\x7A]$ ]] && echo sane || echo nope`

Comment: Related and also asked today: [grep with regex wrongly selects unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77879196/grep-with-regex-wrongly-selects-unicode-characters) (same solution)

Comment: Regarding "The behavior looks consistent with characters between a-z in alphabetical order" - it's a common misconception that there is an alphabetical order in a [bracket expression](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) range but there isn't, there's only "the set of collating elements that fall between two elements in the collation sequence, inclusive". Which characters exist in `[a-z]` is entirely up to your locale setting - it may or may not include capital `A` or `Z`, for example, or some other characters outside of your expected alphabet.

Comment: If you want to match all lower case letters in your locale then use the character class `[:lower:]` inside the bracket expression (`[[:lower:]]`), or if you want to match the characters `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` then use that list of characters inside the bracket expression (`[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]`), never `[a-z]` unless you KNOW that in your specific locale `[a-z]` does contain exactly the set of characters you need it to and/or your tool doesn't support character classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

You are doing something that is *locale-sensitive*, and whose behavior may not be specified by POSIX.  The observed behavior probably is not buggy.

Bash's pattern matching operator uses [the POSIX flavor of regular expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2013edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html), and POSIX leaves the behavior of range expressions inside character classes unspecified except in the POSIX locale.  In the POSIX locale (and maybe elsewhere), the meaning of a range expression depends on the collation order in effect.  It is my understanding that in locales for languages and regions where letters with diacritical marks are in common use, such letters are often collated together with the corresponding base letter.  The behavior you describe is consistent with such a collation order.

If you want to match against the characters mapped by ASCII (and Unicode) to code points 0x61 - 0x7A, and only those, regardless of locale, then the most reliable way to spell that is to list all the matching characters individually:

```
[[ 'š' =~ ^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]$ ]] && echo sane || echo nope
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use ranges; use character classes, which will behave correctly independently of code point ordering. For example, on my machine,

```
bash-5.0$ [[ 'š' =~ ^[a-z]$ ]] && echo sane || echo nope
nope
bash-5.0$ [[ 'š' =~ ^[[:lower:]]$ ]] && echo sane || echo nope
sane
```

(I doubt it behaves differently in 5.1; I get the same results in 3.2 and 4.4 as well.)

Comment: That actually does not fix the issue on [IDEone](https://ideone.com/M7dUIH)

Comment: In what context should Š be considered lowercase?

Comment: I think the OP is specifically trying to detect ascii lowercase and fail all others?

Comment: Looking more closely at the last case, if one cares about collation order, one should use the correct locale.

Comment: (Working on fixing this, if possible; I always have trouble finding correct locales to confirm or reject my assertions...)

Comment: (Also having trouble reproducing; my locale is not notably different, but Š is *not* reported as being in `[A-Z]`.)

Comment: @dawg, ...this is one of those places where I'd suggest using repl.it instead of ideone -- letting the system configuration be specified as a Nix derivation means you can control (and inspect) what locales are built/available, vs getting whatever they give you with no means to know how broken it is.